# helm-projectile startup issue

Tags: helm, projectile

I installed helm and projectile and added the following to my .emacs:

```
(require 'helm)
(projectile-global-mode)
(setq projectile-completion-system 'helm)
(helm-projectile-on)
```

But I get this error when I startup emacs

```
Symbol's function definition is void: helm-projectile-on
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You must `(require 'helm-projectile)` and make sure to install `helm-projectile`. It's a package of its own.

Comment: That did it.  If you add this as an answer, I'll pick it.

Comment: Just FYI, a line like `(setq projectile-mode-line " Projectile")` is also a good idea if you use sudo via tramp. https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile/issues/523.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must add `(require 'helm-projectile)` and make sure to install `helm-projectile`. It's a package of its own.